# How can I make the anchor tag download in a new tab in Chrome?

Tags: html, anchor

How can I get Chrome to open a new tab to download a file using the anchor tag and download property?

I've tried adding a target of "_blank" but this doesn't seem to respect the target due to the download property.

current: a download bar opens at the bottom of the browser
expected: file opens in a new tab with correct file name

```
let pdfFile = new File([fileBlob], fileName, {
  type: "application/pdf"
});

var a = document.createElement("a");

a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile);
a.target = "_blank";
a.download = fileName;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: Should the file simply be opened in a new tab or start downloading directly in a new tab?

Comment: Either is fine as long as I can provide or set the file name in the new tab.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but perhaps you can do:

```
window.open( window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile) );
```

Comment: So, I have tried this option. The issue with using this way is that the pdfURL is not what I want to display as the "file name" that opens in the new tab. window.open gives me no option to set the name of the file that opens in the new tab to my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

write an anchor tag with target blank
see the below code.

```
 <a href={URL} download target={'_blank'} rel="noreferrer">
```

Hope this will solve your problem.